# indentation and spacing problem while copying or going to a new line

Tags: c#, visual-studio, auto-indent

When ever i go to a new line on Visual Studio 2017 or when i paste something all the spacing in between the indentation disturb, by default its 4 spacing in indentation but I am facing a lot more spacing while going to a new line or pasting some code.

I have tried to figure it out from `Tool > Option > Text Editor > C# >` but not find a sol to this

This happening when going to new line or pasting some code :

```
public void problem()
{
            var smile = 0;
            var weep = 1;
}
```

it should be

```
public void Problem()
{
    var smile = 0;
    var weep = 1;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You haven't described a problem yet. If you copy text with tabs, those tabs will be expanded using your settings. The `asp.net` tag and probably the `c#` tag aren't related either

Comment: i found the ans after spending some time in tools

tools > options > Text Editor > C# (or any lang) > tabs > now enter spacing (mine was 10, i changed it to 4 and working fine now.)

Comment: `10` is an arbitrary number. A tab is supposed to represent 8 spaces but Visual Studio and all programming editors use 4. *Someone* changed the setting from 4 to 10

Comment: `arbitrary` means either you did it and forgot about it, or someone is playing a prank

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the explanation, yep that would possibly a prank back then